# Creating new objects and initialising them

Tags: java, object

The assignment question was define a Constructor for class player, it asks to input the players name (which I think I've done correctly), and initialise the position to zero as well to create a players jar by using new Jar();

So I created 2 classes one called Jar and one called Player, basically a players Jar Position is meant to be 0 and a players Stone is meant to be null. (Player position and Jar position are different)

```
public class Jar
{
    public static int position;
    public static Jar stone;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Jar
     */
    public Jar()
    {
        this.position = 0;
        this.stone = null;

    }
}



import java.util.Scanner;

public class Player
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private String name ;
    private int position;
    private Player JarPosition;
    private Player JarStone;


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Player
     */
    public Player()
    {
       System.out.print("Enter player's name: ");
       name = Global.keyboard.nextLine();

       this.position = 0;

       Jar jar = new Jar();
       JarPosition = jar.position;
       JarStone = jar.stone;
```

Comment: Why is `stone` a `Jar`? Why are `JarPosition` and `JarStone` of type `Player`?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code and requirements. Most commonly, a class such as `Player` would have no direct user input and output within it, but instead, the user input (here done with `Global.keyboard.nextLine()`) and the prompting (here, the `System.outprint("Enter...");`would be in a separate class or perhaps the main method, and the Player would have a constructor that takes a String argument for the name and anything else needed. Then after getting the user's information, create a new Player with that information.

Comment: I'm not sure I was just trying something out, would void have been more appropriate for instead of Jar?

Comment: also `public static Jar stone` is defined in class `Jar`, then in your constructor you call `this.stone = null;` meaning you set `stone` to `null` for **every** instance of that class. (static vars are independent from your object instances)

Comment: Don't guess. When you read `private Player JarPosition;` what does that mean to you? I read it as "there's a player named JarPosition", which you probably understand doesn't make any sense. You're also putting `position` in both classes, which will only make it harder for you to understand what's happening.

Comment: Also, consider re-looking at your requirements, line by line, as again, I have a feeling that you're not yet fully understanding them. You might want to post those requirements here, word-for-word.

Comment: 2.2 Jar
Define a constructor for class Jar that initialises the position to zero and the stone to null. This takes about 5 lines of code, ignoring blank lines, and with opening and closing braces on one line each.

Comment: 2.3 Player
Define a constructor for class Player that asks the user to input their name as illustrated in the box below, where the bold text indicates user’s input. This constructor also initialises the position to zero, and creates
the player’s jar using new Jar().

[Enter player’s name: *Joe*]

This takes about 7 lines of code, ignoring blank lines, and with opening and closing braces on one line each. One of those lines should be:
System.out.print("Enter player's name: ");
Another of the lines should include Global.keyboard.nextLine();

Comment: Also I tried ```java private int jarposition``` instead of ```java private Player JarPosition```  cause it seems to make more sense to me the position is an integer value, instead of what kayaman said there's a player named jarPosition.

Answer (score 0):

lets go through it step by step.

First you start your program with a `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     // execute this code here
}
```

This method you can put in any class you like, though I would suggest to put it in a class that you will use to "control" your program's flow:

```
public class MyJarProgram{

    public static void main(String[] args){

    }   
}
```

Now to get rid of all that `static` and non-static confusion, let's keep with "Objects" (instances of classes). Meaning this `main` method is the only static thing you will need.

Now you want to start constructing your players, the jar (I don't really know what that is but nevermind :) and positions and everything, so you might want to start asking the user for the players name:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
     System.out.print("Please enter the player's name");   
     String playerName = Global.keyboard.nextLine();    // I guess this method works like this, so your variable playerName should now contain the user's input

     // now you can instantiate your player object
     Player player = new Player(playerName);   // here we need a constructor of the class player that takes the name.

 }
```

So now you have to create your `Player` class and give it the constructor with the name

```
public class Player{

      private String name;    // make all variables in your classes non-static and private to be on the save-side

      public Player(String name){
          this.name = name;  // you take the parameter name and set the private member variable name to the same value
      }

      // since your variable name is private to the class player you might want to add some standard getter and setter methods like this:
      public String getName(){
          return name;
      }

      public void setName(String name){
           this.name = name;         
      }

}
```

As you did it with the `name` of the player, you could do it with the `position` as well. Give the `Player` class another member variable `position` and add the necessary code to the constructor (and maybe the getter and setters too).

Then your main method could look like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
     System.out.print("Please enter the player's name");   
     String playerName = Global.keyboard.nextLine();    

     Player player = new Player(playerName, 0);  // creates the player with his name and position.
     System.out.println("Player :"+player.getName()+" is on position "+player.getPosition());   // and that's how you can access the players attributes with your getters and setters

 }
```

Although I guess you might want to give the player by default position 0, in which case you don't pass the position in the constructor but set the position to 0:

```
 public Player(String name){
     this.name = name;     // takes the parameter to init the name
     this.position = 0;    // will initialize the position by default with 0
 }
```

Well I hope this helps you get a better idea on constructors and classes and stuff. Good luck!

Comment: sorry to put that in a comment: don't let the `Player` construct itself by calling for user input in the classes constructor or using other classes like `Jar jar = new Jar(); JarPosition = jar.position;`.. try to do this from "outside" the object. If the player has a `jar` then construct it and set it from within your `main` method. (I still don't know what jar means in this context :D sorry )